# How to put a button on the top right corner of a multiline textfield of material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This is my attempt

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-x2578?file=/demo.js:1676-1743)

would like to put the flash icon within the top right corner of the textField without overlapping text and scroll bar

I tried endadornment,
but problem is that the icon will be put on the right of the scrollbar and centered automatically.

Problem:

[image: Problem:]

any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use `endAdornment` like:

```
InputProps={{
        endAdornment: (
          <IconButton>
            <FlashOnIcon />
          </IconButton>
        )
      }}
```

And change the styles like this:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    "& .MuiTextField-root": {
      margin: theme.spacing(),
      width: "25ch"
    },
    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
      position: "relative"
    },
    "& .MuiIconButton-root": {
      position: "absolute",
      top: 0,
      right: 0
    }
  }
}));
```

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]